# How to do Delta Loads into SQL

Tags: database, delta, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

How would you do Delta Loads into Snowflake tables?

I have been looking on snowflakes documentation but I haven't been able to find anything on the topic.

Thanks

Comment: Try Snowflake Merge: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Comment: Delta load can be handled in few ways , it's not snowflake dependent rather it's the way you implement it. As mentioned in the comment above merge is one way. Plain insert if you know there are no old data comming.

Answer (score 1):

`Merge` would be the standard way to do this in Snowflake:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/how-to-perform-a-mergeupsert-from-a-flat-file-staged-on-s3

Comment: You're on a necro roll today. You realise Halloween is still weeks away? ;)

Comment: @MatBailie when you can't find new questions to answer ;)